# Airflow ExternalTaskSensor gets stuck

Tags: python, airflow

I'm trying to use ExternalTaskSensor and it gets stuck at poking another DAG's task, which has already been successfully completed.

Here, a first DAG "a" completes its task and after that a second DAG "b" through ExternalTaskSensor is supposed to be triggered. Instead it gets stuck at poking for a.first_task.

First DAG:

```
import datetime
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator

dag = DAG(
    dag_id='a',
    default_args={'owner': 'airflow', 'start_date': datetime.datetime.now()},
    schedule_interval=None
)

def do_first_task():
    print('First task is done')

PythonOperator(
    task_id='first_task',
    python_callable=do_first_task,
    dag=dag)
```

Second DAG:

```
import datetime
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.operators.sensors import ExternalTaskSensor

dag = DAG(
    dag_id='b',
    default_args={'owner': 'airflow', 'start_date': datetime.datetime.now()},
    schedule_interval=None
)

def do_second_task():
    print('Second task is done')

ExternalTaskSensor(
    task_id='wait_for_the_first_task_to_be_completed',
    external_dag_id='a',
    external_task_id='first_task',
    dag=dag) >> \
PythonOperator(
    task_id='second_task',
    python_callable=do_second_task,
    dag=dag)
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`ExternalTaskSensor` assumes that you are dependent on a task in a dag run with the same execution date.

This means that in your case dags `a` and `b` need to run on the same schedule (e.g. every day at 9:00am or w/e).

Otherwise you need to use the `execution_delta` or `execution_date_fn` when you instantiate an `ExternalTaskSensor`.

Here is the documentation inside the operator itself to help clarify further:

```py
:param execution_delta: time difference with the previous execution to
    look at, the default is the same execution_date as the current task.
    For yesterday, use [positive!] datetime.timedelta(days=1). Either
    execution_delta or execution_date_fn can be passed to
    ExternalTaskSensor, but not both.

:type execution_delta: datetime.timedelta


:param execution_date_fn: function that receives the current execution date
    and returns the desired execution date to query. Either execution_delta
    or execution_date_fn can be passed to ExternalTaskSensor, but not both.

:type execution_date_fn: callable
```

Comment: So if `a` and `b` do run on the same schedule, I don't need to pass either `execution_delta` or `execution_date_fn`, correct?

Comment: @JoshHerzberg I'm fairly certain that is correct, but I have not used this sensor in quite some time.

Comment: And would you know how to monitor a Dag with schedule set as None?

Answer (score 24):

To clarify something I've seen here and on other related questions, the dags don't necessarily have to run on the same schedule, as stated in the accepted answer. The dags also don't need to have the same `start_date`. If you create your `ExternalTaskSensor` task without the `execution_delta` or `execution_date_fn`, then the two dags need to have the same *execution date*. It so happens that if two dags have the same schedule, the scheduled runs in each interval will have the same execution date. I'm not sure what the execution date would be for manually triggered runs of scheduled dags.

For this example to work, dag `b`'s `ExternalTaskSensor` task needs an `execution_delta` or `execution_date_fn` parameter. If using an `execution_delta` parameter, it should be such that `b`'s execution date - `execution_delta` = `a`'s execution date. If using `execution_date_fn`, then that function should return `a`'s execution date.

If you were using the `TriggerDagRunOperator`, then using an `ExternalTaskSensor` to detect when that dag completed, you can do something like passing in the main dag's execution date to the triggered one with the `TriggerDagRunOperator`'s `execution_date` parameter, like `execution_date='{{ execution_date }}'`. Then the execution date of both dags would be the same, and you wouldn't need the schedules to be the same for each dag, or to use the `execution_delta` or `execution_date_fn` sensor parameters.

The above was written and tested on Airflow 1.10.9

Answer (score 1):

As of Airflow v1.10.7, tomcm's answer is not true (at least for this version). One should use `execution_delta` or `execution_date_fn` to determine the date AND schedule of the external DAG if they do not have the same schedule.

Answer (score 1):

From my successful case:

```
default_args = {
    'owner': 'xx',
    'retries': 2,
    'email': ALERT_EMAIL_ADDRESSES,
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(seconds=30),
    # avoid stopping tasks after one day
    'depends_on_past': False,
}

dag = DAG(
    dag_id = dag_id,
    # get the datetime type value
    start_date = pendulum.strptime(current_date, "%Y, %m, %d, %H").astimezone('Europe/London').subtract(hours=1),
    description = 'xxx',
    default_args = default_args,
    schedule_interval = timedelta(hours=1),
    )
```

```
...
    external_sensor= ExternalTaskSensor(
            task_id='ext_sensor_task_update_model',
            external_dag_id='xxx',
            external_task_id='xxx'.format(log_type),
            # set the task_id to None because of the end_task
            # external_task_id = None,
            dag=dag,
            timeout = 300,
            )
...
```

You can wait until the successful automatic trigger for the tasks. Don't do it manually, the start_date will be different.

Answer (score 1):

Airflow by default looks for the same execution date, timestamp. And if we use the execution_date_fn parameter, we have to return a list of timestamp values to look for. Internally, the sensor will query the task_instance table of airflow to check the dag runs for the dagid, taskid, state and execution date timestamp provided as the arguments. So if we use a None schedule, the dag has to be triggered manually and in such a case, the date timestamp might be any possible value.
I have explained it in detail here:
https://link.medium.com/QzXm21asokb

I have created a new sensor inheriting the ExternalTaskSensor and it can be used to monitor dags with None schedule. You can find the code at the below repo.
https://github.com/Deepaksai1919/AirflowTaskSensor

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this as well, but in my case both DAGs were using the same `schedule_interval`, so none of the above suggestions helped.

Turned out it was an Airflow bug.  Templates in the `external_task_id`/`external_task_ids` fields are currently broken in v2.2.4: https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/22782