# AirFlow: How to set large number of external dependencies in one line?

Tags: hadoop, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46807297/airflow-externaltasksensor-gets-stuck) trying to implement dependencies on tasks of other `DAG`s. In this example, dependency is written as:

```
ExternalTaskSensor(
    task_id='wait_for_the_first_task_to_be_completed',
    external_dag_id='a',
    external_task_id='first_task',
    dag=dag) >> \
```

In my data warehouse, one table may depends on hundreds of tasks. Using this format, it will generate `2*number of dependencies` lines of codes. This is really unacceptable, is there any better choice?

For instance, in `Azkaban`, I can write multi dependencies like this:

```
dependencies = dag1.task1, dag2.task4, dag2.task5, DAG3.task2, etc...
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your sensors in a loop and set dependencies within it. I think it's cleaner, but I'm not sure if that meets your requirement regarding amount of code as number of dependencies increase.

Example:

```
dependencies = [('dag1', 'task1'), ('dag2', 'task4'), ('dag2', 'task5'), ('dag3', 'task2')]

other_task = PythonOperator(...)

for dag_id, task_id in dependencies:
    sensor = ExternalTaskSensor(
        task_id='wait_for_{0}.{1}'.format(dag_id, task_id),
        external_dag_id=dag_id,
        external_task_id=task_id,
        dag=dag)
    sensor >> other_task
```